# UIImagePickerController bug Rotate

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, rotation, uiimagepickercontroller

I use UIImagePickerController in my ViewController(Collection View).

When rotate Device I have some bugs following pictures.

1.Portrait Mode : it's OK.

[image]

2.Landscape Mode : it's OK.

[image]

3.Select Action Sheet : UIImagePickerController : it's OK.

[image]

4.Select Camera Roll : it's auto rotate to Portrait

[image]

5.Touch Cancel on Camera Roll : mainViewController auto rotate to Portrait

[image]

**I want**

1) when touch Camera Roll it's show on Landscape mode

2) after touch Cancel and back to mainView , mainView show Landscape

P.S. This Project can Landscape and Portrait, This Problem occur on Landscape ONLY.

Thank you and sorry about my English.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [DOCUMENT](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) it is clearly said that it supports only **PORTRAIT MODE**

[image]

> IMPORTANT
>
> The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is private and must not be modified, with one exception. You can assign a custom view to the cameraOverlayView property and use that view to present additional information or manage the interactions between the camera interface and your code.

So when you go to photo library it will be in portrait mode and when selected a image or cancelled it will come back to whatever previous mode you had.

Comment: But my previous mode is Landscape mode.

Comment: So when you come back from photo library(which will be always in portrait mode) then you will return back to landscape mode. Also I ran a demo regarding your query so I got same. Better read the document.

Comment: Also you cannot change mode of photo library to be clear as per documentation. If you come up with something please let me know and also vote up and click as answer if you finds it so. :)